# Doctrine doesn't find a column when updating the schema

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

When I try to update my schemas, I got this message

```
[@localhost you]$ php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force

  [Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException]                                      
  There is no column with name 'family_id' on table 'unit__family__convert'.
```

This is the beginning of my class UnitFamilyConvert

```
/**
 * UnitFamilyConvert
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="unit__family__convert")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ExclusionPolicy("all")
 */
class UnitFamilyConvert
{
  /**
   * @var integer
   *
   * @ORM\Column(name="family_id", type="integer")
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
   * @Expose
   * @Groups({"All"})
   */
    private $family_id;
```

I already tried to clean the ORM's cache with

```
app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata 
app/console doctrine:cache:clear-query
app/console doctrine:cache:clear-result app/console cache:clear
```

Why Doctrine cannot find my column ?

Comment: Is it a new table/column, which you are trying to add? What will happen when you omit the "--force" flag, and generate only SQL queries for migration? Maybe you are using that column for some FK and doctrine is trying to create FK before adding the new column/table to db.

Comment: table created successfully....

Comment: It doesn't change anything @michaJlS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18164075/4758940
This post helped me.
The `Id` identifier is mandatory, so this is my new class :

```
/**
 * UnitFamilyConvert
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="unit__family__convert")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ExclusionPolicy("all")
 */
class UnitFamilyConvert
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @Expose
     * @Groups({"All"})
     */
     private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Column(name="family_id", type="integer")
     */
    private $family_id;
```